Parsing message out of plain text MIME encoded email stored in database in Python
I have this wall of mime encoded HTML (at least that's what it looks like to me) text stored in our database. I want to extract just the message out of this in python. So, in this case, the message is

Hi Man, ACK. Thanks and Regards, The Engineer

The stored text:
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--/* Font Definitions */@font-face\t{font-family:Wingdings;\tpanose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}@font-face\t{font-family:"Cambria Math";\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}@font-face\t{font-family:Calibri;\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}@font-face\t{font-family:"Segoe UI";\tpanose-1:2 11 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;}@font-face\t{font-family:Garamond;\tpanose-1:2 2 4 4 3 3 1 1 8 3;}/* Style Definitions */p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\t{margin:0in;\tfont-size:10.0pt;\tfont-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}a:link, span.MsoHyperlink\t{mso-style-priority:99;\tcolor:blue;\ttext-decoration:underline;}p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph\t{mso-style-priority:34;\tmargin-top:0in;\tmargin-right:0in;\tmargin-bottom:0in;\tmargin-left:.5in;\tfont-size:11.0pt;\tfont-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;\tmso-ligatures:standardcontextual;}span.EmailStyle21\t{mso-style-type:personal-reply;\tfont-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;\tcolor:windowtext;}.MsoChpDefault\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\tfont-size:10.0pt;\tmso-ligatures:none;}@page WordSection1\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\tmargin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}div.WordSection1\t{page:WordSection1;}/* List Definitions */@list l0\t{mso-list-id:471407872;\tmso-list-type:hybrid;\tmso-list-template-ids:-2117805818 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}@list l0:level1\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l0:level2\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l0:level3\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l0:level4\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l0:level5\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l0:level6\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l0:level7\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l0:level8\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l0:level9\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l1\t{mso-list-id:1600335669;\tmso-list-type:hybrid;\tmso-list-template-ids:-2064323462 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}@list l1:level1\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l1:level2\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l1:level3\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l1:level4\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l1:level5\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l1:level6\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l1:level7\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l1:level8\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l1:level9\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l2\t{mso-list-id:1704405317;\tmso-list-type:hybrid;\tmso-list-template-ids:-724120218 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}@list l2:level1\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l2:level2\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l2:level3\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l2:level4\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l2:level5\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l2:level6\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l2:level7\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l2:level8\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l2:level9\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l3\t{mso-list-id:1793211067;\tmso-list-type:hybrid;\tmso-list-template-ids:-1828796592 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}@list l3:level1\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l3:level2\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l3:level3\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l3:level4\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l3:level5\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l3:level6\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l3:level7\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l3:level8\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l3:level9\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l4\t{mso-list-id:1957178923;\tmso-list-type:hybrid;\tmso-list-template-ids:-795047666 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}@list l4:level1\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l4:level2\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l4:level3\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l4:level4\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l4:level5\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l4:level6\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}@list l4:level7\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0B7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Symbol;}@list l4:level8\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:o;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:"Courier New";}@list l4:level9\t{mso-level-number-format:bullet;\tmso-level-text:\F0A7 ;\tmso-level-tab-stop:none;\tmso-level-number-position:left;\ttext-indent:-.25in;\tfont-family:Wingdings;}ol\t{margin-bottom:0in;}ul\t{margin-bottom:0in;}--></style></head><body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple" style="word-wrap:break-word"><div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">Hi Man,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">ACK.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">---<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Thanks and regards,</span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">The Engineer</span><span style="font-size:11.0pt;color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p></div></div><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p></body></html>


content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)" -> perhaps it's a Word document?

Beutifulsoup library sorted this out for me.
